# Workflow HTTP POST Call Request Headers

Tags: workflow, web-services

I am trying to setup my workflow for SharePoint in which it needs to make a call to an external server using POST on a HTTP web service. I am new to setting this up and created the following request headers and body -

**Request Headers**

> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**Request body**

> appName=test&serverName=test

I have built 2 different dictionaries to do this with, one for the headers and one for the body.

**Dictionary8** -

> Accept - String - 
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>   Content-Type - String - application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**Dictionary9** -

> appName - String - Current Item:App Name
>   serverName - String - Current Item:Server Name

When I submit this it does not work, I have used the same headers and body in a test request in Fiddler and it works. Is something configured wrong?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to build `DynamicValue`:

[image]

Properties for this activity should look like this:

[image]

Then you have to place `HttpSend` activity in the WF designer:

[image]

And pass it RespContent variable which you have built in the first step:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. So it looks like I have to submit using application/json;odata=verbose and there is no way to submit using my current content type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded. So I will need to reconfigure my app to accept the content type if this is correct. Thanks.

Comment: You welcome. Please mark the answer as correct if it solves your problem.